# Publish output project path in ASP.NET5

Tags: gulp, asp.net-core

After publish my ASP.NET5 project I get "output" folder consists of "approot", "logs", "wwwroot" folders. Inside approot/src folder there are folders with dll's of my projects, dependent projects etc. All these dlls I need to copy to my wwwroot folder. The issue is, how to get the information about the current path to my output folder during the publish. I need that information to construct glump task to copy my files to proper destination.

Comment: I think you should use gulp as a pre-publish step ie process your js into wwwroot/js and then your js will be included in the published files. I don't think your grunt task should run after publishing and it should not process files in the published output

Comment: You shouldn't need to move the dlls into wwwroot.  Which web server are you using?

Comment: Yes, I know that, this is unusual approch. I have to use ASP.NET 5 to create host project for my WCF Service. Before, I have been working with ASP.NET 4.6 and than, there wasn't any problems to host my WCF on IIS.  As you might know, new ASP.NET5 have quite new file structure, due to this fact I need to  little reorganize my output folder created after publish. If you ask, why do I need to host my WCF on new ASP.NET5? The answer is,  some parts of my solution are in new ASP, I need to keep reference to them in my WCF project.